# COUNTIF with more than one matching string in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I'm wondering how I can use COUNTIF with more than one matching string in Google Spreadsheets.

The following is the important part, I would like to count in the spreadsheet those records that contain "BAIRRO NOVO" and "Externo". These strings appear in different columns, not in the same cell.

```
=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("10OAEb2fBfvAqCdp1yyuTBQ4NErtxtOyJ29whFkvVqaw";"Data!B:P");"BAIRRO NOVO")
```

Comment: Do you mean the record will literally have both strings in the same cell, like "something Bairro Novo and Externo something"? Or are you looking for rows where one column contains "Bairro Novo" and another has "Externo"?

Comment: Exactly, the later case. I want to count rows where "Bairro Novo" appears and also "Externo" in another column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with [`countifs`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en) but only if the data was placed in the sheet: i.e., `importrange(...)` is done and then `countifs` refers to its columns like

```
 =countifs(C:C, "BAIRRO NOVO", G:G, "Externo")
```

To get this count without putting all the data in the current spreadsheet, use [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

```
=query(importrange(...), "select count(Col1) where Col2 = 'BAIRRO NOVO' and Col7 = 'Externo'", 1)
```

Here Col1, Col2, ... are columns of the imported range; in your case Col2 is C, for example, because the range begins with B. The last parameter "1" is the number of header rows the queried range has: typically 0 or 1.

To make sure the output is a single cell, without a header like "count(something)", add an empty label as follows.

```
=query(importrange(...), "select count(Col1) where Col2 = 'BAIRRO NOVO' and Col7 = 'Externo' label count(Col1) ''", 1)
```

To have the query output 0 instead of #N/A when nothing is found, wrap it in `iferror(..., 0)`:

```
=iferror(query(importrange(...), "select count(Col1) where Col2 = 'BAIRRO NOVO' and Col7 = 'Externo' label count(Col1) ''", 1), 0)
```

Comment: This sound right, but I'm not able to make it working. The following structure returns an error cell, what I'm doing wrong?  `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10OAEb2fBfvAqCdp1yyuTBQ4NErtxtOyJ29whFkvVqaw"; "Data!B:P"); "SELECT COUNT(B) WHERE H = 'BAIRRO NOVO' AND B = 'Externo'";1) `

Comment: I used Col1, Col2, etc in my example. That was for a reason. If the imported range is not placed in the sheet, there are no column names B, H, etc to address it by. It has to be Col + number.

Comment: Sure, but, even though I use the following, I got #REF error. It sounds like the `COUNT` should be paste outside `QUERY`, don't you think. `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10OAEb2fBfvAqCdp1yyuTBQ4NErtxtOyJ29whFkvVqaw"; "Data!B:P"); "SELECT COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col7 = 'BAIRRO NOVO' AND Col1 = 'Externo'";1)`

Comment: The syntax is correct. What does "#REF" error say when you hover over it? One reason may be that the output is more than one cell, and doesn't have room to expand. I edited the answer to address this.

Comment: Now it works @Michelle, thank you. For the counting I've no mention yet I got #N/A, can you edit your answer to return 0, when no mention is found?

Comment: Sure, added to the answer.